# Google Apps Script Email A Copy Of Sheet

Tags: email, copy

I am having difficulty with this code. I makes the copy, sends the email, but the email does not contain the attachment. I would appreciate any thoughts.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var MyNewBook = ss.copy("A Copy of " + ss.getName());

 var MyUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
 MailApp.sendEmail(MyUser, 'TEST', MyNewBook);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about following sample script? The detail information of `MailApp.sendEmail()` is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)

#### Script :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var filename = "A Copy of " + ss.getName();
var MyNewBook = ss.copy(filename);
var MyUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: MyUser,
  subject: 'TEST title',
  body: 'TEST body',
  attachments: [MyNewBook.getBlob().setName(filename)]
});
```

Comment: Thank You, Tanaike. That worked with the exception that the file was emailed as a PDF, not the original Google Sheet - would you know how to adjust that, please?

Comment: @Tacitus It can convert to other types using Drive API. What type do you want to convert to? For example, if you want to convert from spreadsheet to excel file. You can see the detail here. https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/8d639542577a594f6104b7f6fb753064

Comment: Tanaike - this is a Google Sheet, so I would like to email it as a Google Sheet . . .

Comment: @Tacitus Google Docs cannot be exported as the raw Google Docs. It is necessary to convert to other format. So when the raw Google Docs without the conversion is sent by e-mail, the file is automatically converted to PDF as a default format. For Google Docs, you can see the information of format at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

Comment: Thank You, Tanaike. The below code is a bit primitive, I suppose, but it works for now. 
     function myFunction() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var MyNewBook = ss.copy("A Copy of " + ss.getName());
  
     var MyLink = MyNewBook.getUrl()
 
      var MyUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

      MailApp.sendEmail({
       to: MyUser,
      subject: 'TEST title',
      body: MyLink,
       });

       }